# Links i harmon.ie offers a download, not the actual SharePoint document

Tags: sharepoint, harmon.ie

When I attach a link in an email using harmon.ie, I get an url that includes the file name. However when the recipient clicks it, it starts to download a copy instead of opening the actual SharePoint document.

The link is typically on this format:
[company].sharepoint.com/sites/[subsite]/[library]/[filename.docx]

The same link retrieved directly from SharePoint would look something like this:
[company].sharepoint.com/:w:/s/sites/[subsite]/EZ31C3wRKuVPnOOB7vNGMsMBiI9eYAjGTuiaEODu_c3wpw
That link will typically open the document in SharePoint as expected.

It did not use to be like this. The links from harmon.ie used to open documents instead of downloading copies. I am afraid I cannot say when we discovered this, but I believe it was a couple of months ago. We are using the free plan, and are not qualified for support from harmon.ie. We were pointed in the direction of this forum, and I would be most grateful if someone could help us.
Thanks
Eigil

Answer (score 0):

Harmon.ie creates plain valid links to Sharepoint document and they are opened by default browser (like any link you will add inside an email)
The behavior is only controlled by the browser not by harmon.ie (you can check it out by adding the url in the browser)
The only solution to control the behavior is to use the feature to generate OWA link so that it opens in Office online.
Indeed, we have feature allowing to create links that will open in OWA (hence in the browser)
Please read carefully  register key: GenerateOWALinks  as detailed at https://harmon.ie/provision-harmonie-outlook-all-users
Note also that if the recipient of the email has harmon.ie installed, he can right click on the link, select Open in Harmon.ie. The document will appear in harmon.ie sidebar (at the Sharepoint location), double clicking on it with open the document in MS Word.

Thanks,

----- Jean